# Опрeдeлить компьютeр в сeти, до которого самый длинный маршрут

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Нужно **опрeдeлить компьютeр в сeти, до которого самый длинный маршрут**.

То есть максимальное значение последней колонки и сетевой адрес, как я понял. Если кто-то осилит, буду благодарен за помощь.

Скрин:
[image: деловой кот]
<sub>(источник: [freshall.com](http://freshall.com/img/2017-02/27/qmnsvs7q3d2so6a41dh5hs54b.png))</sub>

Мой вариант:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol== tokens=5" %%i in ('route print ^|findstr /rc:"[0-9]$"') do if %%m%% LSS %%i set m=%%i
echo "Max value: "%m%
pause
```

Comment: Обычно `длина маршрута` это количество хостов, через который проходит пакет для достижения конечной цели

Comment: Расстояние можно понять только с помощью tracert и то не всегда верное. например 10.112.238.44 это похоже туннель точка-точка сколько реально переходов через эту подсеть можно понять только если сложить количество переходов внутри туннеля с переходами за которые туннельный пакет добирается до сервера. А по таблице маршрутизации это определить невозможно